# Mixture of thoughts - short riddle

Tags: riddle

I am the mixture of distinguished thoughts,
right on this stage.

Can you tell me who am I?

Monster Hints :

1. > Stage refers to this site.
2. > Those thoughts are more distinguished than a riddle. More distinguished than only being a puzzle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are

> Hot Network Questions

Because

> They come from a mixture of sites, and they are to the right of this page.

Answer (score 1):

> Your sub-consciousness?

It could be miles away from the answer, but it's quite hard with just one clue;
could you maybe add some more?

My reasoning:

> Your sub-consciousness thinks about stuff without you realising, `right on this stage` I suppose could mean in your head?

Am I close? If not could you maybe add another clue?

Comment: Sorry, not the intended answer. The stage doesn't refer to your body part.

Comment: @manshu do you mean this site is the stage?

Comment: well... I think the answer is very near after this comment.

Answer (score 1):

Ok thanks @manshu for that comment.

I think you may be

> A riddle

Why?:

> A riddle is made up of different parts, each 'distinguished', and the 'stage' is this site.

Comment: Nope. Still not the intended answer.  Those thoughts are more distinguished than a riddle. More distinguished than only being a puzzle.

Comment: hmmm, tough one